# Moving unit tests to a different folder in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

When I create a new project Xcode will create a testing target and also a tests folder and group in my project where I add my unit tests. As my project grows I structure my code into folders and groups. I have continued to add all unit tests into the folder created by Xcode and now have a single folder with hundreds of unit test files in one flat folder.

There are two options, I can start to replicate the project structure in my tests folder. What I want to do is stop putting tests in this folder and as I create a new component in my project I have a folder with several source files, I want to put the related tests into that folder under a subfolder called tests.

Tests are added to the testing target not the app target so it will not make any difference from what I can see. I am constantly scrolling up and down in the project navigator searching for the tests related to the code I am working on and vice versa.

I have not found any documentation suggesting that there is any reason they must be separated.

Has anybody tried this approach of mixing the tests and source in the project folders?

Does anybody know of any negative affects that may arise from structuring the project like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to mix test code and production code, and have written about it here: https://qualitycoding.org/rearrange-project-test-code/

The main advantage is that it makes it much easier to find the paired sources. It works great for apps.

The main disadvantage is for libraries, where folks want to be able to take the production code only and build it for themselves. (So for libraries, I keep test code separate.)